# Interface class in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In my desktop application, I am facing a problem in using the function in Interface class.

I have a function like this for executing plugin

```
public static string ExecutePugin(string PluginName, string ConnectionString)
{
    //ToDo: Get the plugin dll in the memory in a different appdomain. call RunAnalysis method of that 
    //ToDo: shift the primary key checking method to inside the plugin and return the result back. 

    //Loads the IMFDBAnalyserPlugin.exe to the current application domain.
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("IMFDBAnalyserPlugin");

    // Load the plugin's assembly to the current application doamin.
    Assembly oAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(PluginName);

    // This block of code will execute the plugin's assembly code.
    foreach (Type oType in oAssembly.GetTypes())
    {
        if (oType.GetInterface("IMFDBAnalyserPlugin") != null)
        {
            object oPlugin = Activator.CreateInstance(oType, null, null);
            ((MFDBAnalyser.IMFDBAnalyserPlugin)oPlugin).ExecutePlugin();
        }
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

where IMFDBAnalyserPlugin class is an interface and contains code like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MFDBAnalyser
{
    public class IMFDBAnalyserPlugin
    {
        void ExecutePlugin();
    }
}
```

but on building the project I am getting the error in MFDBAnalyser.IMFDBAnalyserPlugin as

> Error    1   The type name 'IMFDBAnalyserPlugin' does not exist in the type 'MFDBAnalyser.MFDBAnalyser'  D:\Projects\Mindfire\GoalPlan\MFDBAnalyser\MFDBAnalyser\PluginManager.cs    57  107 MFDBAnalyser

can anyone help me

Comment: There is no `interface class` in C#, only an `interface` or a `class`. I think should be `interface IMFDBAnalyserPlugin`,otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: ...just FYI, that's no interface...

Comment: As listed the `IMFDBAnalyserPlugin` won't compile as it needs to be either marked as `abstract` or an `interface` - is `MFDBAnalyser` in the same project as your `PluginManager`?  If not then are you sure that the assembly containing `MFDBAnalyser` is up-to-date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace MFDBAnalyser
{
    interface IMFDBAnalyserPlugin
    {
        void ExecutePlugin();
    }
}
```

Otherwise `oType.GetInterface("IMFDBAnalyserPlugin")` will be always null because there is no such interface there.

Answer (score 2):

Are you including `MFDBAnalyser` in the usings in the main class?

Something like

```
using MFDBAnalyser;
```

in `PluginManager`?

Also,

you should change

```
public class IMFDBAnalyserPlugin 
{ 
    void ExecutePlugin(); 
}
```

to

```
public interface IMFDBAnalyserPlugin 
{ 
    void ExecutePlugin(); 
}
```

Have a look at [interface (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28VS.80%29.aspx)